# Use `brew` installed applications as default

Tags: applications, homebrew, apple-silicon

I want to install an application (a video player) available through `brew` natively for M1 macs. Is there a way to use that application to automatically play all files with extension `.mp4`, `.mkv` etc?

I'm aware that using `brew-cask` applications this is possible but how to do this for applications without the `cask` version?

Edit 1 :

The application in consideration is `mpv`, a gui-based application.

Edit 2 :

`mpv` brew formula, supported for silicon macs: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mpv

`mpv` brew-cask formula, not supported for silicon macs yet: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/mpv

Comment: Which application is this? Is it GUI-based or commandline-based?

Comment: @nohillside It is GUI based. The question is now updated to reflect the same.

Comment: Can't you just right-click on an mp4 then and select mpv as the default application?

Comment: @nohillside I can do that but only with `brew-cask` applications. The version of `mpv` that I want is not available with the `cask` formula so there is nothing installed in the `Applications` folder on a Mac and hence my question. See for reference the links added in the question now.

Comment: Can't you select "other" in the drop down list of applications, choose enable: all applications, then browse for the binary you want to use?

Comment: @Scottmeup No. It doesn't allow me to select a `binary` and only allows choosing entities with `.app` extension which a binary does not possess. `Brew` people are aware of this and hence they repackage the binaries into nice `.app` packages so that all operations which involve `Applications` type can be performed.

Comment: Best thing I can think of would be creating an applescript .app application that launches the binary, I don't have the syntax to mpv to know exactly what to pass it or if this is definitely viable.